# How to use the same component with different classnames and import and use them in another component with different classnames?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use same component with different props, like classnames, maybe I don't know the syntax or maybe this is impossible. I am trying to do something like this:

```
const MyComp = (class) => (
   <div className={class}>
     ...
   </div>
)

return (
   <MyComp class="icon" />
)
```

Using in another component:

```
const List = ({MyComp}) => {
...
return(
   <div> 
    {MyComp}  // I am asking whether here or before what should I do to change the classname
   </>
)
}
```

Or importing comp like this is not possible(it gives expected a string error when I use like `<MyComp class="anotherStyle" />)`?

Comment: Same way you'd define any other props - the component receives an _object_ as the first argument. Read a basic React tutorial, e.g. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe.

Comment: Should be `({ class })`

Comment: @jonrsharpe it gives error --> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: @Konrad again same error

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this!!
Distruct the props so you can get direct access to it inside that component.

```
const MyComp = ({class}) => (
   <div className={class}>
     ...
   </div>
)

return (
   <MyComp class="icon" />
)
```

Comment: it gives error as I commented above to @Konrad --> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it

Comment: can you please share the whole file code?

Comment: so that we can get better idea

Comment: here I write: const FilterComp = ({abc}) => (
     (<div className={abc} onClick={toggleFilter} ref={filterButtonRef}>
      <FaCogs size={20} color="orangered" />
      <p><b>{showFilter ? "Hide" : "Show"}</b></p>
    </div>)
  )

Comment: return (
          <FilterComp abc={styles.icon} />
  )

Comment: ok I think now I understood. I imported it to different component as prop, the error comes there. How can I import it to different component? Can I import as a prop like this--> const DifferentComp = ({products, FilterComp}) => {  .... return (<FilterComp />)} or must I use only export const method?

Comment: Better to do with export method

Comment: But I cannot export const inside the component, I should use it outside, but then I cannot reach the variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250754/discussion-between-harsh-kukarwadiya-and-jeremyfc).